# Are there LDraw files for the standard Heroica components?

Tags: lego-games, heroica, ldraw

I'm using MLCAD to design and polish some [Heroica](http://heroica.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) maps. As I go I've made various LDraw files for the common map components (6x6 tiles with 4 spaces, 4x1 hallways, etc.) as well as some aliases for simple objects in particular colors (e.g. the gold pickups).

Am I duplicating work someone else has already done? If no one answers this in a few days I'll probably answer with my own archive.

Note that this is not a request for the Heroica sets in LDraw format - I've got manuals for that. I'm more interested in getting parts files that can be used to rapidly build my own levels.)

Comment: I'll bet you're the only one combining bricks.se, Heroica and LDraw for the moment.

Comment: Yeah but at the very least I can hope someone here sees something on another forum I missed. Although Heroica seems to have surprisingly little buzz on the Internet so far.

Comment: I've just seen the value in this, and whole heartedly agree with the sentiments. Not sure how many "typical" players will be up to speed with LDraw though ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I've uploaded the Heroica LDraw parts I made to my website](http://korewanetadesu.com/heroica/parts.html) (and now there's even a site to go with it).

### My Parts

- Paths of length 2 and 4, and rooms in 2x2, L, and J shapes. The base
  and half the tiles can be recolored; the remaining tiles are fixed
  at dark gray.
- The length 3 bridge over a 4x4 water tile, used twice in Fortaan.
- The standard potions with fixed colors, and recolorable potion
  templates.
- The "character sheet" model. The 1 x 4 cross plate is recolorable.
- A treasure chest, fixed as brown.
- A gold piece, fixed as pearl gold.
- A health piece, fixed as red.
- A torch, fixed in color. This uses the unofficial 64647 LDraw part,
  included.
- A closed gate. The standard door piece is not available in the LDraw
  parts library or unofficial list, but the gate used to link Nathuz
  and Fortaan is.
- A magic door, fixed in color.
- Rocks, recolorable and standard dark gray.
- The ship dock, from Draida Bay, and the regular brown starting
  space.

### Included Unofficial Parts

These parts are real Lego parts, but have not made it into the LDraw
part library yet. I've put them on the same site for convenience.

- 62808 - Minifig Key, by Andy Westrate
- 64647 - Minifig Plume/Flame Triple, by Philippe Hurbain. This is
  used as the top of the torches in Nathuz.

### Other Parts

Here are some parts that are invaluable, from the standard LDraw part
library. If you're going to make Heroica levels, they belong in your
MLCAD Favorites.

- 2343 - Minifig Goblet
- 3794 - Plate 1 x 2 with 1 Stud
- 3958 - Plate 6 x 6
- 30153 - Rock 1 x 1 Gem Faceted
- 41539 - Plate 8 x 8
- 64644 - Minifig Telescope
- 85863 - Microfig
- 87580 - Tile 2 x 2 with Groove and 1 Stud

### What do they look like?

Here's a POV-Ray render of the map I'm working on now, sans greebling. Except for the 16x16 center the rooms and paths all use the premade parts, and it features the chest, gold, and potion parts also.

[image: Heroica map, a red center and stone/dirt around it.]

By the way, these are the first reusable LDraw parts I've ever made, so it's possible there's some really horrible failure in them.

Comment: I'll probably be checking these out soon, but they look great!